# Updating HAML & SASS to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, haml, sass

I noticed today that **haml** & **sass** have split in their upgrade to 3.1.

I used to get them both in my Rails project with `gem 'haml-rails'` (though, perhaps I manually added SASS to my gem directory?!? Anyway...)

I'm trying to understand dependencies & whatnot and wondering what I need to do now to get both haml & sass updated to 3.1 in my project(s)...

I see [haml docs](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#plugin) now say to use `gem 'haml'` to get haml...does this mean `haml-rails` is unnecessary/redundant now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my test, you still need `haml-rails` if you want .haml views automatically generated when you run `rails g controller` or `rails g scaffold`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is, yes. I've just started using SASS in my Rails 3  project, and my Gemfile just contains:

```
gem 'haml'
```

... and everything appears to be working fine, as far as I can see.

UPDATE: Just realised I was actually running 3.0.25 when I wrote this post, but `gem 'haml'` already worked at that stage. I've just upgraded to 3.1.1, and it's still working fine :)

Comment: When you `rails g controller...` are your view templates created as `.html.haml`?

Comment: Meltemi: Yes, it generates your view templates as .haml instead of .erb.